# How do I keep my cursor from moving around when in a full screen application?

Tags: c#, bots

Basically, I'm developing a "bot" for training the skills in skyrim automatically. It's just a project for fun, there's no point in cheating in a game that you can do it via console commands.

```
public static void DestructionRestorationTraining(int xpos, int ypos)
    {
        while (true) //i'll try to change it to while(skill's level < 100) later
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(9000); //casts the spells for 9 seconds
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000); //waits 20 seconds to restore mana
        }
    }
```

But when I run it my cursor moves around the screen and never finds my horse, thus not leveling it up. Already tried to set the cursor position to the middle of the screen in every loop, but everytime it does an action it also moves around.